# How to pass a boolean between intents

Tags: android, android-intent, shake

I need to pass a boolean value to and intent and back again when the back button is pressed. The goal is to set the boolean and use a conditional to prevent multiple launches of a new intent when an onShake event is detected.  I would use SharedPreferences, but it seems it does not play nice with my onClick code and I'm not sure how to fix that.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
public class MyApp extends Activity {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private ShakeEventListener mSensorListener;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mSensorListener = new ShakeEventListener();
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);


    mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

      public void onShake() {
             // This code is launched multiple times on a vigorous
             // shake of the device.  I need to prevent this.
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyApp.this, NextActivity.class);
            MyApp.this.startActivity(myIntent);
      }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
      SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
  super.onStop();
}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have a private member variable in your activity called wasShaken.

```
private boolean wasShaken = false;
```

modify your onResume to set this to false.

```
public void onResume() { wasShaken = false; }
```

in your onShake listener, check if it's true. if it is, return early. Then set it to true.

```
  public void onShake() {
              if(wasShaken) return;
              wasShaken = true;
                          // This code is launched multiple times on a vigorous
                          // shake of the device.  I need to prevent this.
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyApp.this, NextActivity.class);
              MyApp.this.startActivity(myIntent);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 82):

Set intent extra(with putExtra):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("yourBoolName", true);
```

Retrieve intent extra:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("yourBoolName");
}
```

Comment: getIntent() is deprecated now.

Comment: @user7856586 Do you have an official source that says that getIntent is deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it in Kotlin :

```
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("sample", true)
            startActivity(intent)

var sample = false
sample = intent.getBooleanExtra("sample", sample)
println(sample)
```

Output sample = true

Answer (score 0):

**SendActivity:**

val intent:Intent = Intent(this,ReceiveAcitivity::class.java)

intent.putExtra("BOOLEAN_VALUE",true)
startActivity(intent)

**ReceiveAcitivity:**

val condition = intent.getBooleanExtra("BOOLEAN_VALUE",false)

Log.d("Condition","intent receive value:$condition")