# Sending a boolean between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

Like the title says, i'm trying to send a boolean from one activity to other.

The sending activity is this.

```
public class ReadyActivity extends Activity {
private TextView text;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ready);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contador);
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            text.setText(""+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReadyActivity.this, StreamingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ready",true);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    }.start();
}
```

And in the receiving activity I have this just for checking the value

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        if(extras.getBoolean("ready")){ // if an extra has been set
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 1 Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Doesn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And it always sends me the Doesn't work message.

I have to add that the sending activity has the Theme.Dialog. 
Does it affect it? 
How can I send and receive the boolean value and get the value?

Comment: it's weird...could you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751564/how-to-pass-a-boolean-between-intents

Comment: Did you retrieve the Bundle inside in the `onCreate`?

Comment: @Enzokie Yes, I have tried it on onCreate, onResume and onStart, nothing works.

Comment: @shanwu I've checked it and i'm still with the problem :/

Comment: let me check it for you @EduardoSanchez

Comment: @EduardoSanchez jianfeng already checked your code for you. you might need to provide more detail.

Comment: Show the rest of the `StreamingActivity` definition, please

Comment: I suggest that you create a new project for practice. It should have two activities. The first activity with a button which starts the second activity and sends a boolean value. The second activity displays a message when it receives the value. The point is to simplify this as much as possible by removing some complications like the timer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on my phone .It was worked.
Maybe it's your activity's launchMode cause.
Check your xml and set your activity default.Try again.

Comment: yeah I agree with you

Comment: It is set as  
android:launchMode="singleTask" Should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try implementing onNewIntent like below :

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //get intent extras here
}
```