# How to use if a condition is success in activity A, i want to use it in Activity B

Tags: java, android

So, i know there's lot of examples with Viewtext and EditText, but i'm struggle with if-else, i have Activity A :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if(Long.parseLong(IMEI) == IMEI2){
            IMEI .equals(IMEI2);
            textView.setText("IMEI NUMBER : " + IMEI);
            Intent intent = new Intent(imei.this, menu_utama.class);
        }else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(imei.this);
            builder.setMessage("Data IMEI and IMEI2 did not match")
                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                .create()
                .show();
        }

    }
});
```

now i want to use : `if(Long.parseLong(IMEI) == IMEI2)` = success
i want to use it in Activity B in an `if(that condition in Activity A success){do something}else{}` condition too. How i do this ?

Comment: Pass a tag via intent to your activity B, check if that tag is true or false and code accordingly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751634/2308683

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and your code, my answer is,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(imei.this, menu_utama.class);
startActivity(intent);     //  Place this line to move Activity B
```

If you know already this line, Use **Bundle**. Bundle can use your previous activity data to another activity.

Comment: i'm trying to put `Intent intent  = getIntent();` inside
`@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        final boolean success = bundle.getBoolean("key");`
it turn red

Answer (score 0):

You can ,using lots of ways:
like

Activity A:

```
//when your condition has been meet

Intent intent=new Intent(context,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra(key,true)  // set true boolean here
startActivity(intent)
```

Activity B:

```
if(getIntent().getExtra().getBoolean(key)){
    // handle your event here
} else{

}
```

Comment: i did in Activity A, but in my Activity B my getIntent() and key is red
if(getIntent().getExtra().getBoolean(key)){}

Comment: turns out my problem has something to do with `public class MyApplication extends Application {}`
but if i try with `extends AppCompatActivity{}` my `getIntent();` correct, what should i do with the rest with my app that has something to do with `extends Application`